# Delete a folder in the currently logged in user's profile

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, vbscript

I am trying to create a login script, or bat file to delete the folder located in the following directory. I would like the whole folder deleted with all of its contents "Juniper Networks".

This is on a terminal server -

C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Juniper Networks

I can write a script for each username, but want a script to put in the startup folder that deleted the folder of the current user each time they login.

I found this script out there, and it works with the specific users ID, but not the %username%

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Juniper Networks\Setup Client")

Comment: Have you tried using the %username% variable?

Comment: I have tried %username%.

Comment: you can't embed the %USERNAME% inside of VBS.  You'd need to grab that when you launch the login script.  say something like "cscript.exe <scriptname.vbs> %USERNAME%" and then grab the command line arguments in the script and parse out the username to a variable.  That way you have the path you want.

Comment: you could grab the username with this  Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")  then username = objNetwork.username   in vbs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a one-liner logon script in a Group Policy Object. Just run `cmd.exe` with the command-line argument `/C rd /s /q "%APPDATA%\Juniper Networks\Setup Client"`.

Comment: I have actually narrowed my issue down to a specific file - 
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Juniper Networks\Setup Client\JuniperSetupClient.ini

Comment: Also wanted to add, this is for Terminal Server. I would most likely just put the Bat file in the All Users Statup folder.

Comment: You can certainly do that. Personally, I almost always have Loopback Merge Mode enabled for Terminal Server computers and would just throw this up as a one-liner logon script (no actual file-- just these items inside the GPO's settings) on a GPO linked to an OU that applied to the Terminal Server. However works, though.